# "will save" both yourself and your hearers (1 Tim.4:16b) - Does "will save" allude, "final salvation" or something else in context of 1 Tim. Ch 4?

Tags: 1-timothy

**Text: 1 Tim. 4:16**

"Keep a close watch on yourself and on the teaching. Persist in this, for by so doing **you will** save   both yourself and  your hearers."(ESV)

"take heed to thyself, and to the teaching; remain in them, for this thing doing, both thyself thou shalt save, and those hearing thee." (YLT)

Answer (score 2):

First, Jesus makes it very clear that eternal salvation is a present reality.  Note the tense of the verbs:

> John 5:24 - Truly, truly, I tell you, whoever hears My word and
> believes Him who sent Me **has** [present continuous] eternal life and
> will not come under judgment. Indeed, he **has crossed** [perfect
> tense - an event already completed] over from death to life.

Thus, the distinction implicit in the OP's question between present and "final" salvation is not sustained by Scripture.

In 1 Tim 4:16, Paul simply asserts that "the teaching" is what will save (after preaching the teaching about Christ's salvation) both Timothy and and those that hear the preaching of the teaching.

Comment: Was Timothy not already a believer ? And did he not, therefore, have eternal life ? He had, as you say, _already crossed_ from death to life. Therefore he preached. So what is the _future_ salvation of which Paul speaks ? And also : _he that endureth to the end_ shall be saved . . . . .

Comment: The future salvation is the eternal salvation which Timothy already had in Christ.  However, Paul's warning is to prevent them from "falling away" as per 1 Cor 9:27, 10:12, 1 Tim 6:10, Heb 6:4-6, 2 Peter 1;10, 2;21, 3:17, etc.

Comment: Correct response. Upvote. It is meet to first analyse the question and find out that already in the question there is an information not sustained by the Scriptures. Of course Paul himself is higher, that is to say, endowed with a greater charisma, greater presence of God's grace (which is the essence of what "salvation" means - the intimacy with God when His grace works in human hearts), but even Paul has to work his salvation (i.e. co-work with the divine presence in him) in fear and trembling; so, how much more Timothy has to do the same and how much more those who listen to Timothy!